# concatenation of strings in bash results in substitution

Tags: linux, windows, bash, macos, string-concatenation

I need to read a file into an array and concatenate a string at the end of each line. Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a lines < ./file.list
for i in "${lines[@]}"
do
    tmp="$i"
    tmp="${tmp}stuff"
    echo "$tmp"
done
```

However, when I do this, an action of `replace` happens, instead of concatenation.

For example, in the `file.list`, we have:

```
http://www.example1.com
http://www.example2.com
```

What I need is:

```
http://www.example1.comstuff
http://www.example2.comstuff
```

But after executing the script above, I get things as below on the terminal:

```
stuff//www.example1.com
stuff//www.example2.com
```

Btw, my PC is Mac OS.

The problem also occurs while concatenating strings via `awk`, `printf`, and `echo` commands. For example `echo $tmp"stuff"` or `echo "${tmp}""stuff"`

Comment: I have checked your code seems fine and found outout as expected
`http://www.example1.comstuff
http://www.example2.comstuff`

Comment: Maybe it's because my PC is Mac?

Comment: can't reproduce, your code gives `http://www.example1.comstuff
http://www.example2.comstuff` for me

Comment: I have tested in Mac and as well as Vagrant box (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: @Yves A poorly titled question with a misleading accepted answer that does little to help the community.  This has the potential to be valuable.  Perhaps you should at least rename the question to something people might search for, and choose a more robust answer than one that doesn't directly solve the core problem but is more of a **possible** workaround.

Comment: @hmedia1   I've made a new title.

Comment: @Yves I faced this problem while parsing output of `ipconfig.exe` within WSL using `awk`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file `./file.lst` is, most probably, generated on a Windows system or, at least, it was saved using the Windows convention for end of line.

Windows uses a sequence of two characters to mark the end of lines in a text file. These characters are [`CR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) (`\r`) followed by [`LF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (`\n`). Unix-like systems (Linux and macOS starting with version 10) use `LF` as end of line character.

The assignment `IFS=$'\n'` in front of `read` in your code tells `read` to use `LF` as line separator. `read` doesn't store the `LF` characters in the array it produces (`lines[]`) but each entry from `lines[]` ends with a `CR` character.

The line `tmp="${tmp}stuff"` does what is it supposed to do, i.e. it appends the word `stuff` to the content of the variable `tmp` (a line read from the file).

The first line read from the input file contains the string `http://www.example1.com` followed by the `CR` character. After the string `stuff` is appended, the content of variable `tmp` is:

```
http://www.example1.com$'\r'stuff
```

The `CR` character is not printable. It has a special interpretation when it is printed on the terminal: it sends the cursor at the start of the line (column 1) without changing the line.

When `echo` prints the line above, it prints (starting on a new line) `http://www.example1.com`, then the `CR` character that sends the cursor back to the start of the line where is prints the string `stuff`. The `stuff` fragment overwrites the first 5 characters already printed on that line (`http:`) and the result, as it is visible on screen, is:

```
stuff//www.example1.com
```

The solution is to get rid of the `CR` characters from the input file. There are several ways to accomplish this goal.

A simple way to remove the `CR` characters from the input file is to use the command:

```
sed -i.bak s/$'\r'//g file.list
```

It removes all the `CR` characters from the content of file `file.list`, saves the updated string back into the `file.list` file and stores the original `file.list` file as `file.list.bak` (a backup copy in case it doesn't produce the output you expect).

Another way to get rid of the `CR` character is to ask the shell to remove it in the command where `stuff` is appended:

```
tmp="${tmp/$'\r'/}stuff"
```

When a variable is expanded in a construct like `${tmp/a/b}`, all the appearances of `a` in `$tmp` are replaced with `b`. In this case we replace `\r` with nothing.

Comment: @hmedia1 I cannot see how your answer explains all the things you say I don't understand. I also cannot see how Ohad's answer you edited answers the question. What if the OP doesn't have a Windows box at hand?

Comment: @hmedia1, your comment would be much more useful if you would point out the inaccuracies of axiac's answer, instead of just claiming there are some. I for one would be very interested in hearing more about what is wrong in it, as I can't really see any issues. Also, if you think the problem in the original question is something other than the carriage return, perhaps you should post your own answer?

Comment: @axiac Thanks for the answer! `${tmp/a/b}` worked perfectly. +1

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it's have something to do with the [Carriage Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character. 
Did your `file.list` created on windows? If so, try to use `dos2unix` before running the script.

**Edit**

You can check your files using the `file` command.

Example:

```
file file.list
```

If you saved the file in Windows Notepad like this:

[image]

Then it will probably come up like this:

- ```
  file.list: ASCII text, with no line terminators
  ```

You can use built in tools like `iconv` to convert the encodings.  However for a simple use like this, you can just use a command that **works for multiple encodings** without any conversion necessary.

You could simply buffer the file through `cat`, and use a regular expression that applies to either:

- Carriage return followed by line terminator, or
- Line terminator on it's own

Then append the string.

**Example:**

```
cat file.list | grep -E -v "^$" | sed -E -e "s/(\r?$)/stuff/g"
```

Will work with ASCII text, and ASCII text with no line terminators.

Comment: There are better ways to check and convert character encodings than having to use third party tools.  This is a very incomplete answer.

Comment: @hmedia1 sure there are. It's just a simple way to indicate that this is the problem (something the OP wasen't aware of)

Comment: `file file.list` would have highlighted if that was a problem, for example: `file.list: ASCII text, with no line terminators` - Again, out of the box and could be integrated into a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify a stream to append a fixed string, you can use `sed` or `awk`, for instance:

```
sed 's/$/stuff/'
```

to append stuff to the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

using "dos2unix file.list" would also solve the problem